# Cannot install R packages on Azure Databricks: null TypeError

Tags: r, azure, databricks, cran

I am trying to install some R CRAN packages on Azure Databricks (for example, the [lime](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lime/index.html) package) using the default way (see screenshots below). This fails with slightly different error messages depending on whether I use Firefox or Chrome:

> Error: TypeError: t is null (Firefox)
>
> Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null (Chrome)

Can anyone reproduce the error or know the reason for this? It might be a problem with the package, or with Databricks...

Screenshot of install:
[image]

Possibly related question: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53345202/cannot-install-r-tiff-library-in-azure-databricks)

Answer (score 0):

Through other channels I found out that this is a bug that was accidentally introduced with the most recent DataBricks update (not sure whether it concerns all of Databricks or just Azure Databricks).

The hotfix is to explicitely state which repository you want to use when trying to install an R package, e.g.

> http://cran.uni-muenster.de/